# Synchronize eclipse projects with my computers

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, synchronization, project-management

Hi and thank you for reading this!

I have two computers in my office LAN: One very powerful PC which i use most of the time for development and a notebook.
Now i would like to share all eclipse projects between these two devices (for example manually sync and then switch to the notebook). I don't need them to be availalbe in a cloud or something. I have also a NAS (network attached storage) which is always running.

Is it possible to synchronize all my projects? The main problem: complexity...

- I use multible eclipse installations with multible addons like Aptana
  Studio, SpringSource Tool Suite, Maven, Git, ...
- Most Projects are Java EE, built with maven (different maven goals like jetty or tomcat)
- Some projects use git for teamwork (with some external partners)
- Some Projects use my own project-builders (external programs)
- I use multible workspaces (i use different workspaces for different customers which include different projects)
- Some projects are inside an eclipse workspace and some are outside

My current solution is to use a file syncronization program which syncs my whole "Projects" Folder (the root for my whole working-life) to a folder inside my NAS (manual sync - not on file change or schedule). The problem with this approach: I have to synch over 100000 files. This takes 20 minutes only to analyze what has changed. And when i open eclipse one time and manipulate one static html file, eclipse changes over 2000 files (most of them are in the .metadata folder)...

I'm open to every solution. Do i have to change the structure of my project setups? Do i have to use another sync solution? Or is it just not possible? Do i have to use an cloud store solution? Would this affect projects which already use git?

Thank you for ANY reply!!!!!

best regards!
Manuel

Comment: Which tool do you use for synchronisation? That might be a first point for optimization.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for reply!
I'm currently using FreeFileSync http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use the FreeFileSync tool from http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/

There is some effort to configure it to ignore some files and folders, but the tool provides nice filter possibilities. Configuring these filters can be very time consuming but they're working fine :)

Thank's for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is possible. How about using git for this scenario? You could create a bare repository on the NAS for those projects that shouldn't be published.

I guess if you deal with source code and really a lot of files this might be the best strategy to do this efficiently and secure (in terms of get-out-what-you-put-in).